# Single sign on in Canvas app as a React component

Tags: reactjs, canvas, single-sign-on, microsoft-teams, powerapps-canvas

We have a Custom app in React embedded in Teams which has SSO from Teams SDK [Teams SSO](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/tabs/how-to/authentication/tab-sso-overview). In this Custom App, we are trying to embed a Canvas App. We have achieved this using @microsoft/powerappsauthoringsdk. This is working fine on Teams Web Client (Browser) but When I logged in to Teams Desktop Client, a Sign-in Screen is being popped up.refer image attached.

Could you please help to achieve SSO (single sign-on) for the Canvas app in react?
[Canvas App on Teams Desktop client](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q56EE.png)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Could you please elaborate your issue. What exactly you want to achieve here.

Comment: @SunilKarampudi - Could you please refer below doc for SSO integratin with Canvas: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/saas-apps/canvas-lms-tutorial